# VisualSVN asking for TortoiseSVN

Tags: visual-studio, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

I have a team of 4 peoples, including me, who are going to work on a project.
I have installed VisualSVN Server on my machine to set it as SVN Server.
Also I have installed VisualSVN Client on my machine and its been integrated with my machine. Here my machine will be a client and server. Server for other users and client for me.

Earlier, I had Tortoise and VisualSVN Client. That time everything was working fine. Now I have removed TortoiseSVN, as I have installed VisualSVN Server. But when I "commit" the changes, VisualSVN says that 
"TortiseSVN is not installed. ....."

Now as I am using both VisualSVN as Server and Client, why should I need TortoiseSVN any more?

Or something is wrong ..?

Comment: Because VisualSVN **requires** TortoiseSVN - see e.g. https://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/download/ *"In order to setup VisualSVN, you need to download and install the latest stable version of TortoiseSVN Subversion client."* If *"everything was working fine"*, why did you change things and not expect something to break?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - Thanks. I had it earlier. But I thought, VisualSVN Server would do the needful.

Comment: Did you not wonder why it asked you to install TortoiseSVN in the first place?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - Yes I did. But then thought it would require a re-start. Also long time have been passed and I forgot about the Tortoise requirement ;)

Comment: VisualSVN is just a shell/wrapper for TortoiseSVN. Pretty much everything is performed via TortoiseSVN actually. You can see most dialogs (update, commit, check out, bramch etc) are actually TortoiseSVN dialogs, VisualSVN just integrates it all with Visual Studio.

Comment: Ok now, I have TortoiseSVN installed on both server and clients. Also I have installed, VisualSVN Server to create groups and users. The path to my repository as shown by VisualSVN server is https://servername/svn/DotNet. The clients are unable to read this. I get "Please wait while the repository browser is initializing..." message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess the reason for your problem is explained on https://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/download/tortoisesvn/

> VisualSVN uses TortoiseSVN for most of the dialogs. But "Add Solution" wizard, "Get Solution" command and Visual Studio integration (status icons, transparent file operations etc.) do not depend on TortoiseSVN.